# ag-grid-angular how to set two colors in one header cell

Tags: angular, typescript

The below is my code:
.ts:

empData = [
{ headerName: 'Department Id'+ this.deptId ,width:39},

{ headerName: 'Name',width:39}
];

my requirement is I need to show  this.deptId alone as red color IN Column header cell

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom renderers for headers (and also individual cells):
https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-header/

You have a fairly simple case, so should be able to follow their basic examples.
The general gist is that you specify a new component that grid will use, and, as it's a standard Angular component, you have full access to do whatever you want.

Note that you have a couple of options - one is to do, per the link, an Angular component, but another is to do a raw JS renderer.

For simplicity, Angular components win, but if you need responsiveness then it's a custom JS renderer jobbie.

Note that this shouldn't really matter for the header as there will only be one of those - if you start creating cell renderers, then you'll need to make the decision based on how much data you'll have and/or how complex your renderers are.

A very approximate, basic custom header component...

```
@Component({
    template: `Department Id: <span style="color: red;">{{deptId}}</span>`
})
export class CustomHeader implements IHeaderAngularComp {
    public deptId: string;

    public anInit(params: IHeaderParams & ICustomHeaderParams): void {
        this.deptId = params.data.deptId; // this is an assumption about your data
    }
}
```

With usage within the column defs...

```
{ ... },
{ field: 'deptId', headerComponent: CustomHeader }
{ ... },
```